# Is it natural for e2fsck taking too much time at force rewrite?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, fsck, badblocks

I have got some bad blocks in my HDD and I can not login now.
I boot from a USB and try to fix it.

Before `e2fsck` I `badblocks -nvs` the partition first so that I know that bad blocks are in `/dev/sda3` (it took a couple of hours).

And…

```
$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sda3 -fcckyv
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
/dev/sda3: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Running additional passes to resolve blocks claimed by more than one inode...
Pass 1B: Rescanning for multiply-claimed blocks
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 1841930: 5236574
Pass 1C: Scanning directories for inodes with multiply-claimed blocks
Pass 1D: Reconciling multiply-claimed blocks
(There are 1 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)

File /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvcuvid.so.470.103.01 (inode #1841930, mod time Thu Jan  6 11:58:25 2022) 
  has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        <The bad blocks inode> (inode #1, mod time Tue Mar  1 13:30:12 2022)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks? yes

Error reading block 5236574 (Input/output error).  Ignore error? yes

Force rewrite? yes
```

After the last line showing, it has been 8 hours and no pregress at all.

This partition was mounted at `/usr`, and it will be fine if just some of the data in it are lost (it just might take me some time to reinstall things according to dpkg logs).

So is it normal for `e2fsck` to take so much time (much, much longer than `badblocks` does) and no progress at all?
What should I do next? Should I just wait?

System info

- Both live CD and the OS in my hard drive are KUbuntu 21.10
- `e2fsck 14.46.3`
- `/dev/sda3` is a partition of my HDD, about 32GB large (while the total space of my HDD is 1TB), its file system is ext4.

Comment: Is this a HDD, or a flash drive? How big total size? How old? `badblocks` should not be used standalone, see `man badblocks` for the reasons. You're doing it correctly with e2fsck. You may just have a bad HDD.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, you are right. I `badblocks` it just for checking. In fact I have mention that my drive is HDD but it seems like I have put it in a not very obvious place.

Comment: @HoyanMok I am currently experiencing something very similar, can you tell me how long it ended up taking?

Comment: @Cronco `e2fsck` did not save my hard drive, I `ddrescure` the contents to the other drive and format the failed one (you'd better go to get a new one). If you are using Debian-based system, get `ddrescure` by `apt install gddrescue`. Good luck!